# Insert only Month and Year date to SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using MS SQLServer and trying to insert a month/year combination to a table like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1111, 'item_name', '9/1998')
```

apparently, the above command cannot work since

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Because `9/1998` is a bad format. I want to fix this and this column of the table will show something like:

```
9/1998
12/1998
(other records with month/year format) 
...
```

Can someone help me with this?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server only supports full dates (day, month, and year) or datetimes, as you can see over on the MSDN data type list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733(v=sql.105).aspx

You can use a date value with a bogus day or store the value as a string, but there's no native type that just stores month/year pairs.

Comment: Or is there a way to display the date in `9/1998` format in table?

Comment: How are you attempting to display it? Are you trying to use a database report or an application?

Edit: If you aren't interested in pulling out a date object and just want a string, you can just store your values as varchars. Those'll come out in the same format you put them in.

Comment: Oh if call `SELECT * FROM MyTable` the MS SQLServer will give out a excel-like table with all records in it. Just want to display the date column in `M/YYYY` format in the table

Comment: Check the edit I just made to my comment above. Storing your values as varchars should do just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old post but my recent tests confirm that storing Date or splitting the year and month to two columns (year *smallint*, month *tinyint*) results in the overall same size. 
The difference will be visible when you actually need to parse the date to the filter you need (year/month).

Let me know what do you think of this solution! :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can just use "01" for the day:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1111, 'item_name', '19980901')
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. What I am trying to do is display the record in this format `9/1998`, and your answer will give a `1998-09-01` which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: In that case you might want to look at SQL Servers DATE FORMAT:
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx
Something like: "YY/MM"

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1) Change the column type to varchar

2) Take the supplied value and convert it to a proper format that sql server will accept before inserting, and format it back to 'M/YYYY' format when you pull the data: `SELECT MONTH([myDate]) + '/' + YEAR([myDate]) ...`

Comment: Can you please write a little bit more detail on how to format it back to `M/YYYY` when pulling out the data? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider what use you will have for your data.  At the moment, you're only concerned with capturing and displaying the data.  However, going forward, you may need to perform date calculations on it (ie, compare the difference between two records).  Because of this and also since you're about two-thirds of the way there, you might as well convert this field to a Date type.  Your presentation layer can then be delegated with the task of displaying it appropriately as "MM/yyyy", a function which is available to just about any programming language or reporting platform you may be using.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use date type, you should format value:

```
declare @a date
SELECT @a='2000-01-01'
select RIGHT( convert (varchar , @a, 103), 7) AS 'mm/yyyy'
```

if you want make query like SELECT * FROM...
you should use varchar instead date type.